# Function Return Mechanism:Temporary object, R-Value, L-Value

Tags: c++, function, assembly, return-value

Analyzing the question on its low level, when a function returns a value, it is returned either in a cpu register, or in a space allocated on the stack previously by the caller.
At this point the calling function can take the value and copy it into its local variable.

```
int sum(int a,int b){return a + b;}

int main(){int risultato = sum(10,20);return 0;}
```

in this case the sum function returns the value in the EAX register. Then the main function copies the value from the eax register into a memory location on the stack.

This is what really happens.

Moving now to the abstraction of C ++, if I tried to do an operation like this:
sum (10.20) = 4;
it gives me an error.
This is because basically the function is not returning the memory location in which the value is contained, but the value itself.
Being therefore an r-value, this will not be assignable, since it is not possible to assign a value to another value.
The issue becomes completely different when the dereferencing operator * is used.
In this case, it will not be returned a value, but the memory location itself (l-value), which will therefore be assignable.

Is what I wrote correct?

Let's take now this second exemple.

```
class class1 {public: int i; int b; class1(int i,int b) { this->i = i;this->b = b; }};
```

`class1 fun() { class1 c(10,5); return c; }`

```
int main() {fun().i = 4; return 0;}
```

in this case the function returns an object.
If I try to execute an instruction like this:
fun (). i = 4; I always get an error.

I know that when the function is called a temporary object is created on the stack.
Returning the function an object , but not as a variable (l-value), but as a set of values, it will not be possible to assign one of these with the value 4.

The same problem also seems to exist with this statement here:

```
class1(10,20).i = 4;
```

In this case I am creating a temporary object, I don't understand why it doesn't give me the possibility to assign the object's variable i, why in this case is it  always interpreted as an r-value and not as an l-value?
I know that what I am doing has no use in practice, but it remains a purely theoretical question, which I need to understand the syntax of language correctly.

Could you comment everything I have said so far, expressing your point of view, and trying to answer the final question?

Comment: *Then the main function copies the value from the eax register into a memory location on the stack.*  Or not, if the optimizing compiler just keeps `risultato` in a register like EAX.  Or optimizes it away completely because in this case it's unused.  In abstract C every object has a memory address (except for `register int foo` variables), but in practice unless you disable optimization variables only have addresses if the compiler runs out of registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Moving now to the abstraction of C ++, if I tried to do an operation like this: sum (10.20) = 4; it gives me an error. This is because basically the function is not returning the memory location in which the value is contained, but the value itself. Being therefore an r-value, this will not be assignable, since it is not possible to assign a value to another value. The issue becomes completely different when the dereferencing operator * is used. In this case, it will not be returned a value, but the memory location itself (l-value), which will therefore be assignable.
>
> Is what I wrote correct?

Kind of.  You say

> This is because basically the function is not returning the memory location in which the value is contained

But that is not what happens.  An object is returned, that object has a value.  What makes it an rvalue is that the function "returns by value" (another name for makes a temporary object).

> Being therefore an r-value, this will not be assignable, since it is not possible to assign a value to another value

This is only true for built in types.  The assignment operator of built in types requires that the object being assigned to be an lvalue.  If you have a user defined type (`class`, `struct`) then you can assign to an rvalue.

> In this case I am creating a temporary object, I don't understand why it doesn't give me the possibility to assign the object's variable i, why in this case is it always interpreted as an r-value and not as an l-value?

The reason is that with `operator .` if the object you call it on is an rvalue, then the member you access is treated as an rvalue.  Since `i` is a built in type, and an rvalue, you can't assign to it.

Comment: I mean that at the point of the code where I call the function it is as if I had a value and not a memory location, when an r-value is returned.
Is this understanding wrong ?

Comment: @Tony92 The C++ abstract machine doesn't make that kind of distinction.  You returned an object by value (created a temporary object) and all temporary objects are rvalues.

Comment: okok Thank you so much. So when I type the name of a function followed by the round brackets, I have to think of that point as a temporary object.
Does the same thing happen even when I use the address operator &?
In that case a pointer (address) is returned and is it always an r-value?

Comment: @Tony92 If you return by reference then you don't have an rvalue anymore.  Having `int global = 42; int& foo() { return global; } foo() = 21;` is legal because references are always considered lvalues.  It really sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  C++ is a very complex language and a proper book is one of the best ways to learn it.

Comment: yes, if I return a reference, which is an automatically dereferenced pointer, I get an l-value.
But if the function returns a pointer, an r-value is returned and not an l-value.
quite right ?

Comment: @Tony92 Yes, if return a pointer by value, then you return a temporary.  Accessing that pointer using `*` though would give you an `lvalue` as `operator *`  returns a reference and a reference is always an lvalue.  `int global = 42; int* foo() { return &global; } *foo() = 21;` would be legal code.

Comment: This shows how a pointer can be both an r-value and an l-value.
int i = 10; int * ptr = & i;
& i -> R-VALUE

ptr -> L-VALUE

.Could I use both, only that the first is not assignable?

Comment: @Tony92 Yep.  You can't do `&i = ptr;`, but you can do `*&i = 42;`

Comment: can therefore be considered & i a temporary object?
Can the concept of pointer also be extended to address only, and not only to the variable containing the address itself?

Comment: @Tony92 `&i` returns a temporary object. A pointer just holds the address of an object.  You have to indirect through the pointer to get the object the pointer points to.

Comment: is it possible having an address that is stored nowhere ?

Comment: @Tony92 I'm not sure exactly what your asking but I'm going to say the answer is no.  What would be the purpose of an address that is stored nowhere?  How would you access such a thing?

Comment: why fun() = class1(4,5) is compiled ?
fun().i = 5 gives error, while fun()=class1(4,5) not

Comment: @Tony92 Like I said in my answer, you are only required to have an lvalue for built in types (`int`, `double`, `char`).  Since `class1` is not a built in type, you are allowed to assign to rvalue objects of it.

Comment: remaining in the context of the temporary object.   int arr[3] = {10,20,30};
; is in this case created a temporary object for the new calculated pointer *(arr+1) = 4 ?

Comment: @Tony92 Conceptually `(arr+1)` will make a temporary but the compiler will most likely optimize that away.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that what I am doing has no use in practice

This is the answer to your question:

> Why in this case is it always interpreted as an r-value and not as an l-value?

It's harder to implement the compiler if it needs to make this an L-Value, and since it has no use, it's not worth the trouble.

There are some things that are just for the convenience of compiler writers.

Answer (score 0):

@NathanOliver answered the C++ abstract machine part.  I'll just add a note about how that maps to asm.

> Then the main function copies the value from the eax register into a memory location on the stack.

Or not, if the optimizing compiler just keeps `risultato` in a register like EAX.  Or optimizes it away completely because in this case it's unused.

In abstract C every object has a memory address (except for `register int foo` variables), but in practice unless you disable optimization variables only have addresses if the compiler runs out of registers.

The return-value object *is* in EAX.

Notice that mainstream C++ calling conventions only ever return trivially-copyable objects in registers.  A non-trivial constructor or destructor will force even a struct of one member to be returned by hidden pointer, to make sure the constructor and destructor have a consistent `this`.  (Calling convention rules can't depend on the content of the constructor and destructor functions, just whether either is defined at all.)